# I have a card component that I need to update to add new items

Tags: reactjs, antd, next.js

I built a card component that shows a list of user data and images with antd on nextJs. I want to build a functionality that creates a modal to input new data and image and adds it to the user interface as a  new card, but I am confused on how to get my hands around it. I need assistance. Here's a link to [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vynk6l2v80)!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Avatar, Card, Icon, List  } from 'antd';

import { ICON_LIST, LIST_TEXTS, STYLES, USER_UPLOAD } from './constants';

const { AVATAR, CARD_CONTAINER, ICON, USER_LIST } = STYLES;
const { INNER, MORE, UPLOAD, VERTICAL } = LIST_TEXTS

class Home extends React.Component {
state = {
    clicks: 0,
};
IncrementIconText = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  }
render() {
    const actions = ( ICON_LIST.map(({ type }) => (
        <span>
            <Icon key={type} type={type} onClick={this.IncrementIconText} style={ICON} />
            {this.state.clicks}
        </span>
    )));
    return (
        <List
        itemLayout={VERTICAL}
        dataSource={USER_UPLOAD}
        renderItem={item => (
            <List.Item style={USER_LIST}>  
                <Card
                    actions={actions}
                    cover={<img alt={UPLOAD} src={item.image} />}
                    extra={<Icon type={MORE} />}
                    hoverable
                    title={<a><Avatar src={item.image} style={AVATAR} />{item.user}</a>}
                    type={INNER}
                    style={CARD_CONTAINER}
                >
                    {item.story}
                </Card>
            </List.Item>
        )}
        />
    );
}
}

export default Home;
```

constants.js

```
export const ICON_LIST = [
{
    key: "heart",
    type: "heart",
},
{
    key: "dislike",
    type: "dislike",
},

 {
    key: "meh",
    type: "meh",
},
]

export const LIST_TEXTS = {
INNER: "inner",
MORE: "more",
UPLOAD: "upload",
VERTICAL: "vertical",
};

export const STYLES = {
AVATAR: {
    marginRight: 8
},
CARD_CONTAINER: {
    width: "650px",
    marginBottom: 50
},
ICON: {
    marginRight: 8 
},
USER_LIST: {
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
},
};

export const USER_UPLOAD = [
{
    image: "http://sugarweddings.com/files/styles/width-640/public/1.%20The%20Full%20Ankara%20Ball%20Wedding%20Gown%20@therealrhonkefella.PNG",
    story: "Today's my birthday next week! What do you think?",
    user: "Chioma",
},
{
    image: "https://dailymedia.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/7915550_img20181007141132_jpeg01c125e1588ffeee95a6f121c35cd378-1.jpg",
    story: "Going for an event. Do you like my outfit",
    user: "Simpcy",
},
{
    image: "https://i0.wp.com/www.od9jastyles.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ankara-styles-ankara-styles-gown-ankara-tops-ankara-gowns-ankara-styles-pictures-latest-ankara-style-2018-latest-ankara-styles-ankara-ankara-styles.png?fit=437%2C544&ssl=1",
    story: "Saturdays are for weddings. Yay or nay!",
    user: "Angela",
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So this could get you started:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1r7j6lom34?fontsize=14

I moved your static `USER_UPLOAD` into the state of `Home` and wrote a method to add a new upload to that state.

You would now need to come up with a component that shows your modal and calls `AddUpload` with the right values.

Also your card-actions don't seem to function properly. To fix that i suggest creating a wrapper component for `Card` that has a state with the appropriate click counters. That way every card has its own clickcounters.

Comment: I have been trying to get my hands around this. But I seem not to get something yet

Comment: @CHIOMAONYEKPERE what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am doing a set up following up an explanation I saw. At this point I am stuck  [link to my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vynk6l2v80) . It's on userProfile